# Saxon EE .NET version evaluation, getting Method not found exception while validating the XSD

Tags: .net, xslt, xsd, saxon

I am using Saxon 10.5 version .NET evaluation version. When trying to compile XSD its throwing below error.

> Method not found: 'Void System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions)'.

```
Processor processor = new Processor(true);
processor.SetProperty("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/timing", "true");
processor.SetProperty("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/validation-warnings", "false"); //Set to true to suppress the exception
SchemaManager manager = processor.SchemaManager;
manager.XsdVersion = "1.1";
manager.ErrorList = new List<StaticError>();
var samplesDir = new Uri(@"C:\saxon samples\samples\");
Uri schemaUri = new Uri(samplesDir, @"data/books.xsd");

try
{
    manager.Compile(schemaUri);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Comment: Can you run the `Validate` command of Saxon EE .NET fine?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you're running on an unsupported version of .NET.

Note that (because of limitations in the IKVM cross-compiler), Saxon isn't currently supported on .NET Core.

Comment: Thank you Michael Kay!...Yes, i am using .Net Core framework.

Comment: The good news is that we're working on it and making good progress.